# uso del Micrófono y que se escuche en tiempo real en un parlante o altavoz (un periferico) utilizando BluetoothSocket , audiotrack ,audioRecord etc

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

quiero que el micrófono del dispositivo se escuche en un parlante o altavoz(periférico), para eso estoy usando bluetoothSocket, audioRecord y audiotrack pero no logro hacerlo, no encuentro el problema mi código es el siguiente:

```
@Composable
    fun Microfono(bluetoothAdapter:BluetoothAdapter?,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,

    ) {
        var context= LocalContext.current

        val sampleRate = 44100
        val channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
        val audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
        val bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat)
        val audioBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat)


        val audioRecord: AudioRecord = AudioRecord(

            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            sampleRate,
            channelConfig,
            audioFormat,
            bufferSize

        )

        val audioTrack:AudioTrack? = AudioTrack.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(

                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build()

            )

            .setAudioFormat(AudioFormat.Builder()
                    .setEncoding(audioFormat)
                    .setSampleRate(sampleRate)
                    .setChannelMask(channelConfig)
                    .build()

            )
            .setBufferSizeInBytes(audioBufferSize)
            .build()

        val audioData = ByteArray(audioBufferSize)


        val pairedDevice: Set<BluetoothDevice>?= bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
        pairedDevice?.forEach {
        }
        var deviceAddress: BluetoothDevice?= pairedDevice?.firstOrNull()
        Toast.makeText(context,"la direccion del dispositivo es $deviceAddress",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        var bluetoothUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("0000110D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")

        if (deviceAddress==null){

            Toast.makeText(context,"el dispositivo no esta sincronizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return

        }

        var bluetoothDevice:BluetoothDevice?=bluetoothAdapter?.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress.toString())

        var bluetoothSocket:BluetoothSocket?= bluetoothDevice?.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(bluetoothUUID)
        try {

            bluetoothSocket?.connect()

        }catch (e:IOException){}

        var outputStream: OutputStream?= bluetoothSocket?.outputStream

        if(true){

            try {
                audioRecord.startRecording()

                Toast.makeText(context, "microfono prendido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }catch (e: IOException){}


            try {
                audioTrack?.play()

            }catch (e: IOException){}

            try {

                while(true){

                    val bytesRead = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, audioBufferSize)

                    if (bytesRead>0){

// Enviar el audio a través de la conexión Bluetooth
                        outputStream?.write(audioData, 0, bytesRead)
                        // Reproducir el audio en el altavoz del dispositivo (loopback)
                        audioTrack?.write(audioData, 0, bytesRead)

                    }

                }

            } catch (e: IOException){

            }

        }else{

            audioRecord.stop()
            audioRecord.release()

            audioTrack?.stop()
            audioTrack?.release()

            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                " microfono apagado",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

        }

    }
```